# Error en el combobox al llegar al final del arreglo

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

hola muy buenas tardes realice un pequeño proyecto en donde hay un combobox que al seleccionar un items me rellena los texbox todo bien el detalle es que si hago el recorrido con una flecha hacia abajo llega el momento en que el programa se pasma y no me deja darle click en el boton de cancelar  [image: ()]

despues de quedarse por asi decirlo pasmado me manda esta cadena de advertencia y seguido de ello me manda este error. me manda a la cadena de conexion[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta seria al desarrollar el algoritmo del combobox hace que me de estos errores al ejecutar el programa adjunto la programacion para recibir ayuda

```
private void btnmodificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion();

        string ver = "SELECT `id`, `codcorto`, `cod_barras`, `descripcion`, `unidad`, `existencias`, `pcom`, `pven`, `departamento`, `proveedor` FROM `productos` WHERE id = id";
        MySqlCommand buscar = new MySqlCommand(ver,conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion());
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(buscar);
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
        adaptador.Fill(tabla);
        cmbproducto.ValueMember = "id";
        cmbproducto.DisplayMember = "descripcion";
        cmbproducto.DataSource = tabla;

    }
```

el codigo del selectchange de combobox

```
private void cmbproducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmbproducto.SelectedValue);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Id = @id";
        MySqlCommand bug = new MySqlCommand(query, conn.conectar.Obtnerconexion());
        bug.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
        var reader = bug.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            txtcodcorto.Text = reader["codcorto"].ToString();
            txtcodigobarras.Text = reader["cod_barras"].ToString();
            txtunidad.Text = reader["unidad"].ToString();
            txtexistencia.Text = reader["existencias"].ToString();
            txtcosto.Text = reader["pcom"].ToString();
            txtventa.Text = reader["pven"].ToString();
            cmbDepartamento.Text = reader["departamento"].ToString();
            cmbProveedor.Text = reader["proveedor"].ToString();

        }
```

"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.'"

Comment: Previamente te funciona la conexion? Veo que abris dos veces la conexion. Cerraste la primera?

Comment: El error es que tienes demasiadas conexiones abiertas. Tal como dice Ramiro, debes cerrar la conexión tras cada SelectedIndexChanged, o montarlo de manera que solo abra la conexión una sola vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en tu programa es que no cierras las conexiones.

El buen método es abrir, usar, cerrar. Para eso existe una instrucción llamada using, que hace dispose automáticamente a todos los objetos que poseen el método object.Dispose(), el cual es el caso de los objetos de System.Data que estas usando, y ademas libera sus recursos automáticamente. Un ejemplo de referencia:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(conString)){

   using (var command = new MySqlCommand){

       /*
        * Instrucciones, etc;
        */

   }

}
```